# How can I control how Jasper Reports combines data for a single value in a time series?

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a time series and I'd like to:

a) Know how Jasper Reports (or JFreeChart) will combine my data for a single point on the chart by default

and

b) Be able to change how that combination is performed

For instance, let's say that I have samples of data once per second, and my time series is configured for "minute". That means that I have 60 pieces of real data for each single value shown on the chart. I'd like to be able to control how that mapping is done (e.g. average, maximum, etc.).

I looked around for documentation on how to see the default or modify how the plot works, but I wasn't able to find anything. Perhaps my search terms (chart, time series, etc.) were too generic.